# Find inequality on a, b and c; if the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has both the roots greater than 2

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics

> **Question**:
>   If the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has both the roots greater than 2 then,
>
> A. $a(b+c)>0$
>   B. $a(a+b) > 0$
>   C. $a(b+c) < 0$
>   D. $a(a+b)<0$

As, both roots are $> 2$, then they should be greater than $0$ and $1$ too. Also, it follows:

$$af(1) < af(0)$$

(with both sides being positive)

$$a(a+b+c)<ac$$

$$\therefore a(a+b)<0$$

But, it's not the correct option. Where am i wrong?

---

The correct option given:

> A

Comment: The *INPUTS* are greater than $2$.  Not the outputs.  If $f(x) = 0$ then $x > 2 > 1 > 0$ but that doesn't tell us anything about what $f(0)$ or $f(1)$ is equal to.

Comment: But the statement as written is still true, because $f(1),f(0)$ have the same sign as $a$, so if $a$ is positive, we have $f(1) < f(0)$ and hence $af(1) < af(0)$, OTOH if $a$ is negative then $f(1) > f(0)$ so $af(1) < af(0)$. The shown logic is correct, implying there are two correct options.

Comment: @fleablood: as the euqation is a parabola, so we can say: $|f(a)| > |f(2)|; \forall a < 2$. @ астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг has explained it much more clearly than me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $2<u\le v$ and $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=a(x-u)(x-v)$

Then,
$a^2+a(b+c)= af(1)=a^2(u-1)(v-1)>a^2$

So, $$a(b+c)>0$$
So, A is correct and C is false.

Your reasoning is also valid, so B is false and D is correct.

Comment: Are you saying there are *two* correct answers?

Comment: Well, they don't contradict each other.  Your logic does seem to be valid.  the graph is a parabola with roots greater than two so either $a > 0$ and $f(0)>f(1) > 0$ or $a < 0$ and $f(0)< f(1)< 0$.  Either way $af(1) < af(0)$.  I guess the author didn't think of int your way.